# Problems applying security patches in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, ssh, magento2.3.6, security-patch

I'm currently attempting to install some security patches on a Magento 2.3.6 instance and don't seem to be able to apply them.

I'm using the files from the following page:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4426353041293-Security-updates-available-for-Adobe-Com

I downloaded the two patches which it said were compatible for 2.3.4-p2 - 2.4.2-p2 and I've loaded them into my root directory as per the image below:

[image]

I'm using SSH via Putty, but when I run the patch command

```
patch -p2 < MDVA-43443_EE_2.4.2-p2_v1.patch
```

I keep getting the following messages

> httpdocs$ patch -p2 < MDVA-43443_EE_2.4.2-p2_v1.patch can't find file
> to patch at input line 5 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip
> option? The text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php
> b/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php |index
> 88b204307f2..52b1018e1af 100644 |---
> a/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php |+++
> b/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] y Skipping patch. 13 out of 13 hunks ignored can't find file to patch at
> input line 222 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The
> text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/DependDirective.php
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/DependDirective.php
> |index f557f7465b5..83345acd6e5 100644 |---
> a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/DependDirective.php
> |+++
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/DependDirective.php
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] y Skipping patch. 2 out of 2 hunks ignored can't find file to patch at
> input line 259 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The
> text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/ForDirective.php
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/ForDirective.php
> |index 2b51185b1b5..41cd58118fd 100644 |---
> a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/ForDirective.php
> |+++
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/ForDirective.php
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] y Skipping patch. 2 out of 2 hunks ignored can't find file to patch at
> input line 297 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The
> text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php
> |index 7fedc7946f2..469dae71d06 100644 |---
> a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php
> |+++
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] y Skipping patch. 2 out of 2 hunks ignored can't find file to patch at
> input line 334 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The
> text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/SimpleDirective.php
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/SimpleDirective.php
> |index 9f4b30d0c96..b9280aec283 100644 |---
> a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/SimpleDirective.php
> |+++
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/SimpleDirective.php
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] y Skipping patch. 2 out of 2 hunks ignored can't find file to patch at
> input line 356 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The
> text leading up to this was:
> -------------------------- |diff --git a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/VarDirective.php
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/VarDirective.php
> |index 78034d70ba5..a7d6790acc7 100644 |---
> a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/VarDirective.php
> |+++
> b/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/VarDirective.php
> -------------------------- File to patch: Skip this patch? [y] y Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored

This happens regardless of whether I use -p1 or -p2.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

**Update**

Thanks to [Shyam](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/40502/shyam) for their advice.

Applying the "Composer" patches in order using the `patch -p1` command appears to have successfully installed the patches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to apply the following patch it works for me without any error,

[image]

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Hello. I tried this one and got the same error using p2 but p1 came up with 
patch: **** Can't create file 2.orig : Too many open files
patch: **** Can't create file 2.origSegmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Hello try with patch -p1 also make sure MDVA-43395 patch first, and then MDVA-43443 on top of it.

Comment: Hello. I'm using the Open source (community) version of Magento. should I still use the patches with COMPOSER in them?

Comment: Yes, you need to apply

Comment: Hello. Thank you. This seems to have applied the patches now.